# Convert Point coordinates to Screen coordinates in JavaFX?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

After looking through several SO posts I have still not found a satisfactory result.

I have, as stated above, a Point and I need to convert it from local- to screen.
When I worked in Swing the `SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen` function would work fine but I am lacking a alternative in JavaFX.

Comment: Just going to throw out that it's difficult to always know what your users' screen sizes will be. Due to this, I believe that it is generally considered better practice to use relative points, so that your application works with all screen sizes.

Comment: *"a Point and I need to convert it from local- to screen."* .. Why?

Comment: The points that I have are recorded mouse clicks and I need to be able to replay them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of [the `localToScreen` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToScreen-double-double-) can be used to transform coordinates in a `Node`'s coordinate system to screen coordinates:

```
Node node = ...
Point2D screenCoordiantes = node.localToScreen(localX, localY);
```

Note that this only works, if the node is added to a scene and the it's shown in a window.

Comment: That seems to result in a NullPointerException

Comment: @user3597322 You need to add this node to a scene first and show the scene in a window.